# How to access get data inside script tag in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get data from inside the javascript portion from window.open function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.open('abc.pdf','_blank')//]]>
</script>
```

I want the abc.pdf link is there a way to get this

Comment: Update the question with the parent tag of the `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

One way is to solve using regex

```
In [33]: html
Out[33]: '<script type="text/javascript">\n//<![CDATA[\nwindow.open(\'abc.pdf\',\'_blank\')//]]>\n</script>'

In [34]: import re

In [35]: group = re.search("window.open\((.*)\)", html)

In [36]: group[1].replace("'","").split(",")[0]
Out[36]: 'abc.pdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve that by saving your page source in a variable and later search it using a regular expression. [As mentioned by @bigbounty]. Please find the code below.

```
mysource = driver.page_source
re.search("window.open\((.*)\)", mysource )
```

Note - I have not tested this code and it should be treated an approach for solving the problem as a whole.